# How to copy data using Google script, writing to "-nth" column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a script that successfully copies data from one Google Spreadsheet to another. What I'm trying to figure out is how to write the data to say Column 5 and not Column 1. When I alter the script to write the data to Column 5, it processes the data but shows a "cell reference out of range" error.

Here is the code that successfully copies data to Column 1.

```
'function copy_data() { 
var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1iQm5NDahmUqXXLDAFvVkrNqooHd2-AAEDVRXndEWXbw').getSheetByName('Account-Category Database');        
var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet25');
var lastdatarow = source.getLastRow();
var criteria = target.getRange('A1').getValue();
var codedata = source.getRange(3,2,lastdatarow,2).getValues();
var codeout = []; 
for (var i=2 in codedata) {
if (codedata[i][0] == criteria || codedata[i][0] == "All") { 
  codeout.push(codedata[i]) 
 }
}
target.getRange(2,1,codedata.length,codedata[0].length).setValues(codedata).sort(2);
}
```

PROBLEM: 
When I change the bottom of the formula to:
`target.getRange(2,5,codedata.length,codedata[0].length).setValues(codedata).sort(2);
}`
That's when I get the "Cell reference out of range" error. Again, the data still copies, it just stops the next function from running because of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I'm just an idiot =)  The error with the code was trying to ".sort(2)"... That means I was trying to sort the target sheet by Column 2, when I was writing data to columns 5... thus Column 2 was out of range... Changing it to ".sort(5)" corrected the issue.

Hopes this helps others understand their potential future issue.